# Creating a dynamic asp.net link list

Tags: asp.net, webforms

My project is built on the WebForm architecture. It uses role-based authorization of the standard ASP.NET Identity mechanism. I had a question how to dynamically create an html markup fragment, for example, if the role is an administrator, then the user sees the markup like this:

```
<li><a runat="server" href="~/WebLogisticTool>UploadContainerExcel</a></li>
<li><a runat="server" href="~/Home>Home</a></li>
<li><a runat="server" href="~/AdminPanel>AdminPanel</a></li>
```

if the role is a manager then:

```
<li><a runat="server" href="~/About>About</a></li>
<li><a runat="server" href="~/Home>Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Look into a `BulletedList` Control.

Answer (score 0):

Create table with userrights with menu options.
While login get data from this table for menu options and bind this options using

element or using Repeater control